# Ideal sample class ratio for training CNN for 2 class classification

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

What should the ratio of the positive to negative samples be if I am training a CNN for binary classification?

Comment: (This seems clear enough to be answered to me--& it has an answer. This can stay open, IMO.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:1.
You should have same amount of both.

If you don't there is a number of techniques to handle it.
The most common/simplest being *over-sampling* and *under-sampling*.

When you *over-sample*,  you duplicate some of the underpressenented class, and present them again.

When you *under-sample* you discard some of the over-represented class.

Point being either way, you want to present the same number of each.
For positive, then negative, then positive ...

If you do not have roughly balanced numbers of each class, then the network will learn the distribution of the classes -- rather than learning only (/mostly) from the features of the classes.

Comment: I'm not even sure what a relable citation for this is.
It is not in  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~vincentp/ift3395/lectures/backprop_old.pdf
nor in http://svn.ucc.asn.au:8080/oxinabox/Uni%20Notes/honours/Background%20Reading/lecun2012efficient.pdf
Which are generally my go to source for this  kinda things

Comment: Thanks ! But I also forgot to mention that I am trying to detect people from background. Thus negative samples could be in the form of cars, buses, streetlights, anything really. Would a 1:1 ratio still suffice ? The CIFAR-10, Imagenet dataset have a specific set of images for each class. One of my class however (the negative one) would be very unspecific on the kind of images it has thus I am not sure if I should generate more positive samples to 'enforce' the CNN to learn filters that describe the pedestrian class...

Comment: I would still go one for one, cos other wise the network simply learn the bias towards the ratio of negative positive. But I am no expert on CNN's for image processing.